# Why Hadoop FTPFileSystem.listStatus(Path path) doesn't work?

Tags: java, hadoop, ftp, hdfs

I want to transfer file from FTP server to HDFS. I tried this method: [FTP to HDFS](http://hadoop101.blogspot.com.ar/2011/12/ftp-to-hdfs.html), the demo code as follows:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FTPFileSystem ftpfs = new FTPFileSystem();
ftpfs.setConf(conf);
ftpfs.initialize(new URI(ftpConnectStr), conf);

Path homeDirectory = ftpfs.getHomeDirectory();
System.out.println(homeDirectory.toString());

FileStatus[] fileStatuses = ftpfs.listStatus(new Path("/"));
for(FileStatus fileStatus : fileStatuses){
    System.out.println(fileStatuses.length);
    System.out.println(fileStatus.toString());
}

boolean test = ftpfs.mkdirs(new Path("test"));
System.out.println(test);
```

The `ftpfs.listStatus(new Path("/"))` doesn't work, it shows nothing, but the FTP server has two directories and `ftpfs.mkdirs(new Path("test"))` work fine, the program running result as follows:

[image]

and the FTP server dirctory as follows：

[image]

I searched in google，but find a little information. I don't know why. If you can help me, I will be very grateful，thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you have found out, the problem is because Hadoop (or rather the underlying Apache Common Net `FtpClient`) defaults to the FTP active mode, which hardly works nowadays due to ubiquitous NATs and firewalls.

Since Hadoop 2.9, you can set up FTP passive mode by setting [`fs.ftp.data.connection.mode` configuration option](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.html) to enable the FTP passive mode:

```
fs.ftp.data.connection.mode=PASSIVE_LOCAL_DATA_CONNECTION_MODE
```

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13953

Answer (score -1):

Finally,I found the problem where it is; In FTP Server,the data tansfer mode is set to passive.

[image]

Then I debuged the source code of FTPFileSystem,and i found that it didn't set FTP passive mode;

[image]

so,I modify the related code of FTPFileSystem to this:

[image]

Rerun the program：

[image]

and it works fine:

[image]